# ASP.NET validation - is client one enough

Tags: validation, asp.net-4.0

There's an ASP.NET WebForms page. It has some validators.

My question is, is the client validation enough or I must also check validated values on the server after postback? In other words, must I also use server validation and how do I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **always** check on the server side. What if the client has javascript turned off? What about a carefully crafted request?

Comment: If it's turned off then it's unable to press the submit button.

Comment: there are way for a different client to POST back a custom request with bad data too.